# wxPython - Adding a BoxSizer to a ScrolledPanel

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, sizer

I'm building a window where I want to build a really simple calendar. I the loop of **_organizeData**, every time there is a new month, I want to add some buttons to a GridSizer, which is inside a vertical box with a text on the top. I can't figure it out to **add this vertical BoxSizer (vBox) to the scrollPanel**. self.data will be a structre like this, a list of dictionaries:

> [{'date': '14-03-2021', 'xyValues': [[01:00, 02:00, ...], [18.5, 17.2,
> ...]]}, ...]

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class GraphCalendar(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.data = data
        self.consumption = []
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, label="This is a test")
        self.scrollPanel = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=((400, 600)), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.scrollPanel.SetupScrolling()

        self.topVerticalBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.topVerticalBox.Add(self.text, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.topVerticalBox.Add(self.scrollPanel)

        self.Center()

        self._organizeData()

    def _organizeData(self):

        currentMonth = ''

        for i in range(0, len(self.data)):
            words = self.data[i]['date'].split('-')  # words -> [0]day, [1]month and [2]year.

            if currentMonth != words[1]:
                currentMonth = words[1]
                vBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
                # Name of the month / year.
                text = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, f"{(words[1])} of {words[2]}")
                # Grid where the button of the days will be added
                gridSizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=5, cols=5, hgap=5, vgap=5)

                vBox.Add(text, wx.ID_ANY)
                vBox.Add(gridSizer, wx.ID_ANY)


            # Create the button of the day and add it to the gridSizer.
            button = wx.Button(self, 1000 + i, label=words[0], size=((20, 20)))
            button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClicked)
            gridSizer.Add(button, border=5)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.topVerticalBox)


    def OnButtonClicked(self, event):
        """ Funcao chamada quando um botao e apertado. """

        event.GetEventObject()
        print(event.GetId())

app = wx.App()
frame = GraphCalendar(None, data=[{'date': '14-03-2021', 'xyValues': [['01:00', '02:00'], [18.5, 17.2]]}, {'date': '15-04-2021', 'xyValues': [['01:00', '02:00'], [19.5, 18.2]]}])
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This is the desired output:

[image: Intended result]

This is what the code above produces:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `sizer`. You have a sizer for buttons, another for months and a main sizer for self, but nothing for the scrolled panel. I think you'll need another vertical sizer, set that as the sizer for the scrolled panel. It's sometimes difficult to tell because you've shown us what you want but not what you have.

Comment: self.scrollPanel is already added to the self.topVerticalBox in the __init__. What I want to know is how I add the gridSizer to the self.scrollPanel. I don't know what else to do. Do you want a working code? I'll try to leave it a code that runs.

Comment: What I mean to say is to the add the vBox to the self.scrollPanel. PS: I have modified the code to run now. I should have 2 vBox (day 14 of month 3 and day 15 of month 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the final solution but it should point you in the right direction.
I've added an extra sizer (as mentioned in my comment) for the scrolled panel and removed the erroneous assignment of `wx.ID_ANY` to the `proportion` parameter when you added items to `vBox` ( Lord knows what the sizer thought of a proportion of something like -31000 ).

You might want to consider restructuring your data, before you start, because as it is, it's a bit ungainly.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class GraphCalendar(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.data = data
        self.consumption = []
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, label="This is a test\nof my text placement above a calendar of sorts")
        self.text.SetBackgroundColour("lightgreen")
        self.scrollPanel = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=((400, 600)), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.scrollPanel.SetupScrolling()

        self.topVerticalBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sp_vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.scrollPanel.SetSizer(self.sp_vbox1)
        self._organizeData()
        
        self.topVerticalBox.Add(self.text, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.topVerticalBox.AddSpacer(10)
        self.topVerticalBox.Add(self.scrollPanel)
        self.SetSizer(self.topVerticalBox)

        self.Center()

    def _organizeData(self):

        currentMonth = ''

        for d in self.data:
            words = d['date'].split('-')  # words -> [0]day, [1]month and [2]year.

            if currentMonth != words[1]:
                if currentMonth != '':
                    self.sp_vbox1.Add(vBox)
                currentMonth = words[1]
                vBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
                # Name of the month / year.
                text = wx.StaticText(self.scrollPanel, wx.ID_ANY, f"{(words[1])} of {words[2]}")
                # Grid where the button of the days will be added
                gridSizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=5, cols=5, hgap=5, vgap=5)

                vBox.Add(text)
                vBox.Add(gridSizer)


            # Create the button of the day and add it to the gridSizer.
            button = wx.Button(self.scrollPanel, wx.ID_ANY, label=words[0], size=((60, 20)))
            button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClicked)
            gridSizer.Add(button, border=5)

        self.sp_vbox1.Add(vBox)


    def OnButtonClicked(self, event):
        """ Funcao chamada quando um botao e apertado. """

        event.GetEventObject()
        print(event.GetId())

app = wx.App()
frame = GraphCalendar(None, data=[{'date': '14-03-2021', 'xyValues': [['01:00', '02:00'], [18.5, 17.2]]}, {'date': '15-04-2021', 'xyValues': [['01:00', '02:00'], [19.5, 18.2]]}, {'date': '16-04-2021', 'xyValues': [['01:00', '02:00'], [19.5, 18.2]]}, {'date': '19-04-2021', 'xyValues': [['01:00', '02:00'], [19.5, 18.2]]}, {'date': '11-05-2021', 'xyValues': [['01:00', '02:00'], [19.5, 18.2]]}, {'date': '15-08-2021', 'xyValues': [['01:00', '02:00'], [19.5, 18.2]]}])
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. That exactly what I needed. In mine, that gorgeous green color don't appear, but thats ok (win10). Just one little question. If I want to add color to the vBox, do I need to assign it to Panel or something? Thanks! :)

Comment: @NeoFahrenheit Colour is assigned to the widget. So in this case, probably the scrolled panel but you could also add colour to `text` and `button`. I've altered the image to reflect that.

Comment: You colored the text of the date and the buttons, but I would like to color also the SizerBox those widgets are in, so they could appear more "separate" (each month), you know. You helped me alot already. I feel bad asking more of you. I can figure it out by myself. Thanks. :)